# Floating multiple elements in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this demo (http://jsfiddle.net/vp3Q3/) I would like the first tab to stay in same position until it reaches second tab and then second tab stays in same position until third tab etc...

I managed to build that first tab jump to then end of first div but what I need is not to jump to the end but to float smoothly down as I scroll.

Is this possible?

This is my code

```
  function makeItFloat() {

    //alert('g');
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $("#test" + i).position({
            my: "left-35 top",
            at: "left top",
            of: "#imgDiv" + i
        });
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    makeItFloat();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        makeItFloat()
    });
}
```

Comment: You mean, something like a sticky element that adheres to the top of the viewport when scrolled past? p/s: Bad idea to use `<table>` for layout.

Comment: This is just example to show what I mean hence <table>. But to answer your question : yes :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this by relatively positioning the tabs unless they're the one 'selected/active', in which case the receive a class which gives them fixed positioning. To accomplish this you'll need to monitor the scroll position, browser height and offsets of all of your tabs. It can get expensive on performance.

Note: there is a css positioning property 'sticky' that's being developed, but it's not going to be ready for production for some time. http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit